# is it possible to set up exclusion/inclusion filter in Flash Builder to have wildcard in the beginning?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, profiler

Is it possible to set up exclusion/inclusion filters in profiler to have wildcard character in the beginning?

For example, let's say we have packages org.foo, org.bar, and com.foo and i want to filter for any package names that has foo in it. In this case I want something like *.foo.*.* but that doesn't seem to work. is there any way to do what I want? or do i have to set up filter for every package that has foo in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package declaration is pretty much just the folder structure of where the package is located. So if i understand what you are asking for is a way to load all "foo" classes in a directory branch. The answer is no.

However, The other thing you can do is load all packages in the "foo" directory with "com.foo.*" this will load all "foo"s, but you still need to know where "foo" is located.

Comment: yeah that's too bad... I'm mainly trying to use this with the actionscript codecoverage plugin which has same exclusion/inclusion filter as the profiler. I was using FlexCover before and used a python script someone wrote which took regex to filter out package names. so I was able to do stuff like *foo* and get all packages with foo in it. i guess i have to manually list out all package names with foo in it then...